# Bar chart for displaying min/max/avg

Tags: charts, highcharts, google-visualization, jfreechart, bar-chart

**Update:** I would take any chart library, not just Google charts:

I would like to use the [Google Charts: Bar Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) for visualising rows of acess statistics displayed with min/max values as bars and avg values with a horizontal line.

I managed to display the min/max values (just stack the series for min and max):
[image: Min/Max Bar Chart]

The code (for entering in the [Code playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart)) is

```js
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Function', 'Min', 'Max'],
    ['functionA',  0,    150],
    ['functionB',  11,    100],
    ['functionC',  20,    150],
    ['functionD',  5,    7],
    ['functionE',  0,    22],
    ['functionF',  23,    55]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Min/Max Demo",
            width:600, height:400,
            isStacked: true,
            hAxis: {title: "Duration [ms]"}
           }
      );
}
```

Now I want to integrate the average value to get something like:
[image: Min/Max/Avg Bar Chart]

Can anyone give me some hints how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample in Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/27/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']
        },
        series: [ {
            name: 'max',
            stacking: true,
            color: 'red',
            data: [
                [100],
                [120],
                [50]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'min',
            stacking: true,
            color: 'blue',
            data: [
                [13],
                [50],
                [1]
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'avg',
            color: 'black',
            data: [
                [44],
                [55],
                [12]
            ]
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Thansk for the solution! Is it also possible to have one arry with all the data as in the question (actually the avg is missing there) instead of having to split it up?

Comment: Highcharts by design requires different bars/markers to be in different series.

Comment: Good solution! 
BUT: You have to take care to subtract the value [min] from the [max] before, because the max-bar is attached to the min-bar.
Example "f1" max:100, min:13 -> shows max up to 113. This is ok, if you subtracted it correctly before.

Comment: Good point. In that case, simply remove `stacking` options and instead set `grouping: false`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8youz03e/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are searching for a javascript solution ... but your question was tagged with jfreechart ... so here is the jfreechart code: (... in case of a webapp, you would need to provide the image e.g. via a rest service)

```
import java.awt.*;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.*;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.*;
import org.jfree.data.category.*;
import org.jfree.ui.*;

public class StackedAndLevelChart extends ApplicationFrame {

    public StackedAndLevelChart(final String title) {
        super(title);
        final JFreeChart chart = constructChart();
        final ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    JFreeChart constructChart() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset barDS = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        Object [][] vals = {
            {"Function", "Min", "Max"},
            {"functionA",  0,    150},
            {"functionB",  11,    100},
            {"functionC",  20,    150},
            {"functionD",  5,    7},
            {"functionE",  0,    22},
            {"functionF",  23,    55}
        };
        for (int i=1; i<vals.length; i++) {
            barDS.addValue((Number)vals[i][1], (String)vals[0][1], (String)vals[i][0]);
            barDS.addValue((Number)vals[i][2], (String)vals[0][2], (String)vals[i][0]);
        }

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(
            "Min/Max demo",              // chart title
            null,                        // domain axis label
            "duration [ms]",             // range axis label
            barDS,                       // data
            PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL,  // the plot orientation
            true,                        // legend
            true,                        // tooltips
            false                        // urls
        );

        DefaultCategoryDataset levelDS = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        double [] avg = { 0, 48, 20, 70, 5, 10, 45 };
        for (int i=1; i<avg.length; i++) {
            levelDS.addValue(avg[i], "avg", (String)vals[i][0]);
        }

        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
        chart.getLegend().setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);

        CategoryItemRenderer renderer1 = plot.getRenderer();
        renderer1.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
        renderer1.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.RED);

        CategoryItemRenderer renderer2 = new LevelRenderer();
        plot.setDataset(1, levelDS);
        plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);
        plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);


        renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
        renderer2.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(5.0f));        

        return chart;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackedAndLevelChart demo = new StackedAndLevelChart("");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: At first prio I would prefer a JS solution, but if none is available I would take anything :-) - your example works great, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems a standard box plot chart should give you exactly what you're wanting, yet it is a very standard chart type. I'd find a way to draw a box plot with your data. Or am I missing something?